# Is it possible to load object and reuse said object in separate HTTP call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

So I have a WEB API, for example I have this method :

```
public JSONResult GetUserInfo(string username)
{
    Reddit reddit = new Reddit("bot12345", "12345"); //load reddit and login
    reddit.GetSubmittedVideos(username);

    var user = User.Get(username);

    //rest of the code here
}
```

You can see that I have this line `Reddit reddit = new Reddit("bot12345", "12345")`, this line took almost 2 seconds because it needs to login through Reddit API. So everytime someone call `GetUserInfo` method, my code will take more than 2 seconds to return the results because it needs to call Reddit.

I was wondering if it's possible to load Reddit object so inside my GetUserInfo method, I only need to call `reddit.GetSubmittedVideos`. But I remember that HTTP is stateless, so is that possible?

Apologize for bad english.

Comment: Do you have information about Reddit session lifespan ? you might try to safe all logined instances of regddit durring the first run in the dictionary that would be shared accoss application (static or singleton) with the user name as a key. And it`s more likely that you would have to store login time - to refresh connection

Comment: can you be more specific about this? Maybe you can post something like a code so I have the idea. Reddit session lifespan should be permanent.

Comment: will do, please wait 10 minutes ... seems like Stanley already have done that )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP *is* stateless, but ASP.NET has a `Session` object that is isolated to one user session and can store data that persists across requests. So at a minimum you could do something like:

```
Reddit reddit = Session["reddit"] as Reddit;
if(reddit == null)
{
    reddit = new Reddit("bot12345", "12345"); //load reddit and login
    Session["reddit"] = reddit;
}
reddit.GetSubmittedVideos(username);
```

If the same `Reddit` object can be used for *all* user sessions, then you can use the `Application` class instead of using `Session`.